# How to make focus() work before the DOM element shown

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

**UPDATE: it turns out there is no way to directly apply focus to textbox before DOM rendering finished**

---

I wonder why the focus() function does not work on hidden element.

For example( I am using Vue.js ):

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    showtext: false
  },
  methods: {
    showTxt(ev){
      this.showtext = true
      var vm = this;
      // if I uncomment setTimeout, then the textbox can set focus
      //setTimeout(function(){
        vm.$refs.textbox.focus()
      //}, 0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="showTxt">
    Show Textbox and SetFocus on it
    </button>
    <div v-show="showtext">
        <input ref="textbox" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to click that button and show textbox and put focus in textbox, but currently, the textbox can not get focus if I directly call .focus(). It only works when I wrap a setTimeout around it(which I guess run on the next event loop). I wonder if there is any way to make the focus working without setTimeout?

Thanks

Comment: You're wondering why you can't draw a user's attention to something not on their screen?

Comment: well you have to wait until it is visible on the page to focus it. So guessing the rendering takes awhile.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It makes sense what you're saying and that's why I upvoted your comment. But, I have always wondered why can't these high powered rendering engines queue these operations in the back. Like, i just made something visible, and I want to set focus to it. Just because you're slow, it's not really my fault. (By you i mean the rendering engine.)

Comment: Vue and other frameworks could perhaps create their own versions of things like `focus()` that queued them until the next tick, but watch someone complain that they call `focus()` and it doesn't happen immediately. Or they call it on an invisible element and forget, then 5 minutes later another command shows the element and they yell "why is this thing stealing my focus!!!1!" :).

Answer (score 4):

**Preferable** to use `vm.$nextTick` or `Vue.nextTick` (We don't need to care about `nextTick` even actually uses `setTimeout`, Vue will guarantee `nextTick` will do its job, even in future `nextTick` may use other approaches implement same goal).

As [Vue API: nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) says,

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use
> it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM
> update.

Also you can check [Vue Guide: Async Update Queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

For your case, when click the button to show the input, it will execute `this.showtext=true`, then execute `element.focus`. But actually the Dom element is still invisible (**VNode is changed, but Vue hasn't re-render&patch**).

So you have to use `vm.$nextTick` or `Vue.nextTick` to execute `.focus` **after** Vue re-render that input out.

Check the demo below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    showtext: false
  },
  methods: {
    showTxt(ev){
      this.showtext = true
      var vm = this;
      console.log('Current:', this.$el.innerHTML)
      this.$nextTick(()=>{
        vm.$refs.textbox.focus()
        console.log('Nexttick:', this.$el.innerHTML)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="showTxt">
    Show Textbox and SetFocus on it
    </button>
    <div v-show="showtext">
        <input ref="textbox" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Why **setTimeout** works:

because `setTimeout(,0)` adds one task to the task-queue. But it will be executed at **next event loop**, but render will be exeucted after execute micro-tasks in **current event loop**.

Check [HTML SPEC: event loop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model)  (please look into **Step 7**), after current task (including this.showtext to true, data reactivity triggers re-render) already executed (it will be removed from task queue), the system will **render first** before pop one task (probably is `setTimeout(,0)` if `setTimeout(,0)` task is the oldest task) from the queue.

But **Promise is micro-task**, it will **not work** because it will be executed **before render** (please look into above *event loop processing model*: **step 6**).

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    showtext: false
  },
  methods: {
    showTxt(ev){
      this.showtext = true
      var vm = this;
      new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        vm.$refs.textbox.focus()
        resolve()
      }).then(()=>{
        vm.$refs.textbox.focus()
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="showTxt">
    Show Textbox and SetFocus on it
    </button>
    <div v-show="showtext">
        <input ref="textbox" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can look into this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0), it will decribe better than mine.

Comment: Can you explain what it does to people that have no clue about vue?

Comment: nextTick uses setTimeout, the irony.

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of `setTimeout` only if you use other means of setting focus, for example `autofocus` attribute. Without it you will have to separate setting `showtext` flag and call for `focus` into separate event "ticks".

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    showtext: false
  },
  methods: {
    showTxt(ev){
      this.showtext = true
      this.$refs.textbox.focus()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="showTxt">
    Show Textbox and SetFocus on it
    </button>
    <div v-show="showtext">
        <input ref="textbox" autofocus type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kuan `autofocus` doesn't work on iOS, just fyi, if your use case involves that. It works on [these platforms](https://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus).

Comment: @rmn Well if mobile matters for this then yes, autofocus won't work in mobile safari.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks, I am not familiar with how autofocus works, but I really like this idea. Only one question: if I have multiple input textbox, and all of them have autofocus attribute, how focus order get decided?

Comment: @Kuan I'm afraid It can be not unreliable in this case. I would use setTimeout or nextTick. For precise focus control you can't avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden elements cannot get focus by the nature of focus entity concept. Only visible and enabled ones. In any UI system, HTML/CSS DOM included.